# How to use jquery and javascript without jquery_ujs in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My code:

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to("test", {:controller => 'user', :action => 'create'} , :remote => true ) %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
alert('click from crate.js.erb');
```

If I don't use `//= require jquery_ujs` and `:remote=>true`, i get an error.

How i use jquery without `jquery_ujs` and `:remote true`?

Comment: You're saying you just want the user to click on your link_to and see the user#create page?

Comment: no, he wants to use the remote feature without the ujs. funny

Comment: @HuanSon; @MarsAtomic; : i want using '<%= link_to("test",:class="btn-me" ) %> 'and js external in app/assets/javascripts/something.js with jquery onclick without ':remote => true' .. what it can?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rails 3: Using link_to :remote => true with *jQuery UJS***

The Rails Unobtrusive Javascript (UJS) library provides two main pieces of functionality:

> You can add add **:remote => true** to link_to and the link will be
> submitted via AJAX.
>
> You can add **:remote => true** to form_for and the
> form will be submitted via AJAX.

there is no way to use this feature without the jQUJS
of course you could do this by yourself - but better question yourself why you dont want to stick with ujs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i want using '<%= link_to("test",:class="btn-me" ) %> 'and js external in app/assets/javascripts/something.js with jquery onclick without ':remote => true' .. what it can?

Comment: So use the Assets Pipeline and Include the ujs in external